# How to create multiple instances of the same widget with different data?

Tags: android, kotlin, widget, instance

I have this widget with a RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory adapter to populate a ListView.
How would you retrive different data for each widget instance if the RemoteViewsFactory is always the same (unless it got killed)? The data is choosen by the user with a Configure activity on widget creation by the way.

Thanks to anyone who can provide even the smallest input.